# ASP.Net Mvc 3 webservice repository authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, authorization

We are starting with a new application build with Asp.net. It should connect to a webservice which is already available to retrieve data to present to the user. We've created a repository which communicates with the webservice.

The webservice needs authorization with the same user credentials which the user uses to logon to the web application. The user is authorized with Forms Authentication with cookie support.

The problem is that we cannot retrieve the password from the user on new requests when the user is once authorized and automatically logged on. This password is needed to logon to the webservice from the repository classes.

Any ideas on how to implement this the best and safest way ?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488676/asp-net-wcf-service-requires-windows-authentication?rq=1

Comment: It is *ALWAYS* the wrong answer if you need to retrieve the users password.  No solution should require that a users password be retained, only password hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Client Application Services to get and set the cookie. Or you can manually get and set the cookie using the sample code on this post. The example shows both methods and is geared specifically to passing a forms authentication cookie from an MVC application to an OData WCF feed:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-7-forms-authentication.aspx

Also, here is a similar example that is trimmed down in scope:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190806/Send-Cookies-When-Making-WCF-Service-Calls